# Are there any advantages in playing with lower sensitivity & DPI in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Recently, I started watching eSports. I'm interested in CS:GO. I found that pro players play with really low (for me) sensitivity: [~0.6-2.2 and low DPI](http://csgopedia.com/csgo-pro-setups/).

So, I'm playing the game with about **6** (in-game) and **1500 DPI**.

Are there any advantages in playing with lower sensitivity & dpi?

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain? (:

Comment: Most likely because this question is pretty subjective. Which is something that is to be avoided on this forum.

Comment: This question is *very* opinion based.. it's just about personal preferences. Some people can play on a bottle cap and others need a whole desk for their mouse and still perform equally good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my oppinion, most of it is about the personal feeling and the capability of aiming. If you play a high sensivity and you actually are able to aim nicely, I don't see a reason, why to change that. Most of it is about muscle memory, so if you stick to your mouse speed, you will be very used to it and feel nice with it.

Back in the days, till CS:GO I was messing around with my sensivity settings a lot and I was trying to figger our my personal favor. With less inpact from outside (pro players and so on), I started lowering my in-game sensivity to about 2.0 and the mouse DPI to 600. With this setup, i am doing fine for the last couple of years (besides, my skill group is GE). Even with the AWP, I am capable of performing flick shots and make fast kills. Besides: Consider that you need to have a lot more space (e.g. a large mousepad) with low settings.

Additionally, i think that professional players for the most part don't need a high scence, cause they have a high map awareness. Through team communication, mini map and other stuff, they always know whats going on. However, in match making for intence, you will not be able to share this kind of experience.

Taking everything into account, in my mind, it's all about your feeling which you got in-game. If you feel great having a high sensivity (and you actually hit something) there is no need for you to lower it, even if most of the professional players are using a low mouse sensivity. I'd recommend to use a mouse with a good quality to have a well precision (you will definitely recognize the difference). Additionally, it might be interessted what intensions you have. Do you want to become a real professional player or just be a good player in match making.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was just wondering how I can improve my games, other than learning smokes, flashes, callouts, etc so I can enjoy the more. The thing about having high sensitivity is that my hand gets tired quite easily (because it's under constant pressure), but I don't play more than 1-2 hours every other day so it's fine.